# Index tensor must have the same number of dimensions as input tensor error encountered when using torch.gather()

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm very new to PyTorch, and I have encountered the "Index tensor must have the same number of dimensions as input tensor" error when running my neural network. It happens with I call an instance of torch.gather(). Could someone help me understand torch.gather() and explain the cause of this error?

Here is the code where the error occurs:

```
  def learn(batch, optim, net, target_net, gamma, global_step, target_update):
      my_loss = []
      optim.zero_grad()
  
      state, action, next_state, reward, done, next_action = batch
      qval = net(state.float())
  
      loss_a = torch.gather(qval, 3, action.view(-1,1,1,1)).squeeze() #Error happens here!

      loss_b = reward + gamma * torch.max(target_net(next_state.float()).cuda(), dim=3).values * (1 - done.int())
      loss_val = torch.sum(( torch.abs(loss_a-loss_b) ))
      loss_val /= 128
      my_loss.append(loss_val.item())
      loss_val.backward()
      optim.step()
      if global_step % target_update == 0:
          target_network.load_state_dict(q_network.state_dict())
```

In case it is helpful, here is the batch function that creates the batch that the action comes from:

```
def sample_batch(memory,batch_size):
    
    indices = np.random.randint(0,len(memory), (batch_size,))

    state = torch.stack([memory[i][0] for i in indices]) 
    action = torch.tensor([memory[i][1] for i in indices], dtype = torch.long)
    next_state = torch.stack([memory[i][2] for i in indices])
    reward = torch.tensor([memory[i][3] for i in indices], dtype = torch.float)
    done = torch.tensor([memory[i][4] for i in indices], dtype = torch.float)
    next_action = torch.tensor([memory[i][5] for i in indices], dtype = torch.long)

    return state,action,next_state,reward,done,next_action
```

When I print out the different shapes of 'qvals', 'action', and 'action.view(-1,1,1,1)' this is the output:

```
qval torch.Size([10, 225])
act view torch.Size([10, 1, 1, 1])
action shape  torch.Size([10])
```

Any explanation as to what is causing this error is appreciated! I want to understand more what is going on in the code as well as how to fix the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Torch.gather is described [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html). If we take your code, this line

```
torch.gather(qval, 3, action.view(-1,1,1,1))
```

is equivalent to

```
act_view = action.view(10,1,1,1)
out = torch.zeros_like(act_view)
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(1):
         for k in range(1):
              for p in range(1):
                   out[i,j,k,p] = qval[i,j,k, act_view[i,j,k,p]]
return out
```

which obviously makes *very little* sense. In particular, `qval` is not 4-D and thus cannot be indexed like this. The number of `for` loops is determined by the shape of your input tensors, and they should all have the same number of dimensions for this to work (this is what your error tells you by the way). Here, `qval` is 2D and `act_view` is 4D.

I'm not sure what you wanted to do with this, but if you can explain your goal and remove all the useless stuff in your example (mostly the training and backprop related code) to get a minimal reproducible example, I could help you further in finding the correct way to do it :)